# How to group taxonomy and node flags together?

Tags: views, flags

I have 2 view block displays. One view displays flagged nodes and other displays flagged taxonomies. I need to print latest 8 flagged contents (nodes + taxonomy) in a single display sorted by title or term name, in ascending order.

Any suggestions about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) module. Excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR conditions for contextual filters.

Create a view using 2 contextual filters (=both of the filters you already have for your 2 views), and combine them with an **OR**.